# SQL Server -- Improve Speed of Cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using the below code to check if column `@act_value` is above 24.0 for a specific row, looping through each row of the table with a cursor. If `@act_value` is above 24.0, then several operations will be completed as well as updating that entry and inserting a new entry. That said, the query takes over 26 min to run (up from 0:16 min prior to this addition provided below) and perhaps too resource intensive. Is there a better configuration that can speed up this operation?

```
DECLARE cur_hours_check CURSOR
FOR
    SELECT 
       Period, Act_Batch_Time, Kg_Per_Hour, Total_QT_Produced, 
       Total_Possible_KG,
       --The columns not affected but need for inserting the shadow day
       Division, Region, Business_Region, Plant, Work_Center, DaysInMonth, 
       Total_Possible_Hours, Demonstrated_Capacity
    FROM 
       zt_Demonstrated_Capacity_Trend

OPEN cur_hours_check

DECLARE             --Cursor Variables Pulling data
    @period                   datetime
,   @act_hours                float
,   @over_hours               float
,   @Total_QT_Produced        float
,   @KG_per_hour              float
,   @Total_Possible_KG        float
--then the extra
,   @Division                 varchar(20)
,   @Region                   varchar(20)
,   @Business_Region          varchar(20)
,   @Plant                    varchar(40)
,   @Work_Center              varchar(40)
,   @DaysInMonth              float
,   @Total_Possible_Hours     float
,   @Demonstrated_Capacity    float

DECLARE             --Cursor Shadow variables:
    @shadow_period                 datetime 
,   @shadow_act_hours              float
,   @shadow_Total_QT_Produced      float
,   @shadow_Total_Possible_KG      float
,   @shadow_Percent_of_Total_Hours float

DECLARE             --Cursor adjusted first day variables
    @adj_act_hours                 float
,   @adj_Total_QT_Produced         float
,   @adj_Total_Possible_KG         float
,   @adj_Percent_of_Total_Hours    float

FETCH FROM cur_hours_check
    INTO @period, @act_hours, @KG_per_hour, @Total_QT_Produced, @Total_Possible_KG
   ,@Division, @Region, @Business_Region, @Plant, @Work_Center, @DaysInMonth, @Total_Possible_Hours, @Demonstrated_Capacity

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    IF @act_hours > 24.0
    BEGIN
    -- Setting the shadow period to carry over values relative to 24 hour time window
        SET @shadow_period = dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, @period) + 1, 0) 
        SET @shadow_act_hours = @act_hours - 24.0
        SET @shadow_Total_QT_Produced = (@Total_QT_Produced - (@KG_per_hour * @shadow_act_hours))
        SET @shadow_Percent_of_Total_Hours = (@shadow_act_hours/24.0)*100

    -- Adjusting first period for 24 hour window of operation
        SET @adj_act_hours = 24.0
        SET @adj_Total_QT_Produced =  @Total_QT_Produced - (@KG_per_hour * 24.0)
        SET @adj_Total_Possible_KG = @Total_Possible_KG *(1-( @shadow_act_hours/@act_hours ))
        SET @adj_Percent_of_Total_Hours = 100

    -- now update that record, as well as insert the shadow day
        UPDATE zt_Demonstrated_Capacity_Trend
        SET Period = @period
        , Act_Batch_Time = 24.0
        , Total_QT_Produced = @adj_Total_QT_Produced
        , Total_Possible_KG = @adj_Total_Possible_KG
        , Kg_Per_Hour = @KG_per_hour
        , Percent_of_Total_Hours = @adj_Percent_of_Total_Hours
        , Division = @Division
        , Region = @Region
        , Business_Region = @Business_Region
        , Plant = @Plant
        , Work_Center = @Work_Center
        , DaysInMonth = @DaysInMonth
        , Total_Possible_Hours = @Total_Possible_Hours
        , Demonstrated_Capacity = @Demonstrated_Capacity
        WHERE CURRENT OF cur_hours_check 

    --Inserting the shadow record
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[zt_Demonstrated_Capacity_Trend](
        [Period]
        ,[Division]
        ,[Region]
        ,[Business_Region]
        ,[Plant]
        ,[Work_Center]
        ,[Kg_Per_Hour]
        ,[Total_QT_Produced]
        ,[Act_Batch_Time]
        ,[DaysInMonth]
        ,[Total_Possible_Hours]
        ,[Demonstrated_Capacity]
        ,[Total_Possible_KG]
        ,[Percent_of_Total_Hours])
        VALUES
        (@shadow_period
        ,@Division
        ,@Region
        ,@Business_Region
        ,@Plant
        ,@Work_Center
        ,@Kg_Per_Hour
        ,@shadow_Total_QT_Produced
        ,@shadow_act_hours
        ,@DaysInMonth
        ,@Total_Possible_Hours
        ,@Demonstrated_Capacity
        ,@adj_Total_Possible_KG
        ,@shadow_Percent_of_Total_Hours)
    END
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur_hours_check
    INTO @period, @act_hours, @KG_per_hour, @Total_QT_Produced, @Total_Possible_KG
   ,@Division, @Region, @Business_Region, @Plant, @Work_Center, @DaysInMonth, @Total_Possible_Hours, @Demonstrated_Capacity

END;

CLOSE       cur_hours_check
DEALLOCATE  cur_hours_check
```

Comment: First things first, use set-based operations whenever possible. eliminate the IF statement, run only the operations, and put the requirement in your cursor declare statement. Use a WHERE clause there, don't use an IF on fetched values if the effect is you're doing nothing on rows that don't match the criteria. Next, eliminate the cursor entirely (per marc_s). Use a predicated update statement followed by a predicated insert...select statement.

Comment: @JaazCole thanks, just adding the where in the cursor def and eliminating the if, reduced the time to 2:43, from 34 min, thanks! If you want to write up the answer I can select that one

Comment: I have a better one....

Comment: Use my edit! The Act_Batch_Time should be used instead of Period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using TSQL for set-based operations like it was intended, I've taken the modifications to the variables you've used and set up a sample at [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8055d/1) that accomplishes splitting a single record of greater than 24 hours into many 24 hour ones with the remainder. Here's the work:

```
BEGIN TRAN
INSERT INTO zt_Demonstrated_Capacity_Trend (
        -- The Columns we care about modifying
        period, Act_Batch_Time, Total_QT_Produced, KG_per_hour, Total_Possible_KG, Percent_of_Total_Hours
        -- The rest that you aren't touching in your procedure
        , Division, Region, Business_Region, Plant, Work_Center, DaysInMonth, Total_Possible_Hours, Demonstrated_Capacity, over_hours
    )
SELECT
    -- Add a day equal to the rows we generate
      DATEADD(dd,ShadowDays, Period) AS Shadow_Period
    -- Hours we generate
    , ShadowHours AS Shadow_Hours
    -- Our Hours times the rate is total produced
    , Kg_Per_Hour * ShadowHours AS Shadow_Total_QT_Produced
    -- Unmodified Kg_Per_Hour
    , Kg_Per_Hour
    -- Unmodified Kg_Per_Hour times 24 is total in a day possible.
    , Kg_Per_Hour * 24.0 as Total_Possible_KG
    -- Our hours divided by hours in a day
    , ShadowHours / 24.0 * 100 AS Shadow_Percent_of_Total_Hours
    -- the rest
    , Division, Region, Business_Region, Plant, Work_Center, DaysInMonth, Total_Possible_Hours, Demonstrated_Capacity, over_hours
FROM zt_Demonstrated_Capacity_Trend T
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
            ROWID-1 AS ShadowDays
            , CASE WHEN CAST(T.Act_Batch_Time AS NUMERIC(38,15)) - ROWID*24 > 0 THEN 24 ELSE CAST(T.Act_Batch_Time AS NUMERIC(38,15)) % 24.0 END AS ShadowHours
        FROM (
            SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY S.NAME) AS ROWID
            FROM master..spt_values S
            ) X
        WHERE T.Act_Batch_Time - ((ROWID-1)*24) > 0
    ) Z
WHERE T.Act_Batch_Time > 24

DELETE FROM zt_Demonstrated_Capacity_Trend WHERE Act_Batch_Time> 24
COMMIT TRAN
```

Using a cross apply, and getting artificial rows where we can split a given value, I then use the Hours and days to put into the select statement in various ways to get your intended effect. You want this isolated in a single transaction to prevent new inserts between the insert and delete statement. This will perform way better than your cursor with predicate.