# Summing between timestamps

Tags: sql, timestamp, calculated-columns

I have a data set that is based around timestamps, i.e. startdate, enddate. I would like to calculate the number of business hours between the time stamps, say for a typical (M-F,8-5) week.

For example, if a ticket came in at 8:00 am Monday, and was closed 9:00 am Tuesday, I would like the statement to show 10 hours. I also need to omit weekends from the calculation. Could anyone recommend an approach to solving for this? Thank you for you assistance.

Comment: I suggest subtracting the latter date from the former and converting to hours/minutes, and `CASE` logic to handle non-work-hours.

Answer (score 0):

As an example (without having your table structure in front of me), here's what I came up with based on another answer I did for [generating rows for time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24271898/sql-server-improve-speed-of-cursor/24273376#24273376).

```
declare @datetimes table (id int primary key identity(1,1), startdatetime datetime, enddatetime datetime)
insert into @datetimes (startdatetime,enddatetime) values
      ('2014-08-26 08:00:00','2014-08-27 09:00:00')
    , ('2014-07-16 08:00:00','2014-07-28 09:00:00')

declare @defaultDayStart time = '08:00:00', @defaultDayEnd time = '17:00:00'

select T.ID, sum(Z.ShadowHours)
from (
        select id, startdatetime, enddatetime, datediff(hh,startdatetime,enddatetime) TotalTime
        from @datetimes 
    ) T
    CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT
                RowID-1 AS ShadowDays
                , CASE
                    WHEN DATENAME(dw,DATEADD(dd, RowID - 1,t.startdatetime)) IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday') THEN 0
                    ELSE DATEDIFF(hh, CASE RowID WHEN MIN(RowID)OVER(PARTITION BY t.id) THEN t.startdatetime ELSE CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(dd, RowID - 1,t.startdatetime))) + @defaultDayStart END
                            , CASE RowID WHEN MAX(RowID)OVER(PARTITION BY t.id) THEN t.enddatetime ELSE CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(dd, RowID - 1,t.startdatetime))) + @defaultDayEnd END
                            )
                END AS ShadowHours
                , DATENAME(dw,DATEADD(dd, RowID - 1,t.startdatetime)) wd
            FROM (
                SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY S.NAME) AS RowID
                FROM master..spt_values S
                ) X
            WHERE DATEDIFF(dd,startdatetime,enddatetime) + 1 >= RowID
        ) Z
GROUP BY T.id
```

This example is rudimentary, and doesn't make use of a calendar table containing, for example, holidays. This also does no calculations regarding lunch hours, which should be in there as most places regard it as illegal not to grant a meal break of some sort for 8 hour work days. These are considerations you'll likely be asked to adapt this for. Edit your question and leave me a comment if you'd like assistance in this realm.